# A function divisible by $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I want to ask about what is the intuition for making functions like these

- $4^n+2$ is divisible by $3$
- $ 2^{4n+2}+3^{n+2}$ is divisible by $13$

And if so, how can I make my own ones?  Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Do you know modular arithmetic?  $4^{n}+2\equiv1^{n}+2\equiv1+2\equiv0\pmod3$

Comment: The "intuition" is modular arithmetic. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I know the basics of modular arithmetic

Comment: @J.W.Tanner like as an example i know about its properties and congruence no more than that

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple explanation using the binomial theorem:
$$
4^n+2 = (3+1)^n+2 = 3a + 1 + 2
$$
and
$$\small
2^{4n+2}+3^{n+2} 
=4 \cdot 16^n + 9 \cdot 3^n
=4 \cdot (13+3)^n + 9 \cdot 3^n
=13a + 4 \cdot 3^n + 9 \cdot 3^n
=13a + 13 \cdot 3^n
$$

Comment: Thank you alot dude well done

Answer (score 1):

These are easy to see with modular arithmetic.

$4^n+2\equiv1^n+2\equiv1+2=3\equiv0\pmod3$ and

$2^{4n+2}+3^{n+2}=4^{2n+1}+3^23^n=4\times4^{2n}+9\times3^n\equiv4\times3^n+9\times3^n=13\times3^n\equiv0\bmod 13.$

Comment: Thank yoy so much ♥️, that's fascinating, i guess i wasn't thinking of modular arithmetic nor any manipulation at all

Answer (score 1):

"How to make my own ones":

a) Choose your favourite natural number (works best for primes), like $17$.

b) Play with basic congruences in $\mathbb Z/17$, like $33=-1$, $9=1/2$, $5\cdot 7=1$.

c) Write down an obvious formula like $(-1) + 4\cdot 1/2 -1=0$. Make it look more complicated, like $(-1)^{2n+1} + 4\cdot 1/2 -1^n=0$

Insert c in b: $33^{2n+1}+4\cdot3^2 -5^n\cdot 7^n = 3^2(11^{2n+1}\cdot 3^{2n-1}+4)-5^n\cdot7^n$ is divisible by $17$.

Comment: Based on other answers i was able to make something like this for 5,7 and 9 thw best trick is that if we use prime numbers in our function or atleast numbers in there reduced form so that we can disguise our function